# Conversion from Fahrenheit to Celsius Method in Java

Tags: java

```
package n.pkg09;

/**
 *
 * @author hachaudh
 */
public class N09 {

    public static double CtoF(double Celsius) {

        System.out.println("Celsius |   Fahrenheit");
        System.out.println("");
        for (int i = 0; i <= 50; i++) {
            Celsius = (i * (9.0 / 5.0)) + 32;
            System.out.printf("%4d     |    ", i);
            System.out.println((int) Celsius);

        }

        return Celsius;
    }

    public static double FtoC(double Fahrenheit) {

        System.out.println("Fahrenheit |   Celsius");
        System.out.println("");
        for (int i = 150; i <= 220; i++) {

            Fahrenheit = (i * (5.0 / 9.0) - 32);
            System.out.printf("%4d       |    ", i);
            System.out.println((int) Fahrenheit);

        }

        return Fahrenheit;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //CtoF(0);
        FtoC(0);
    }
}
```

In the method FtoC (Fahrenheit to Celsius the conversions are all of 212 is suppose to equal 100 here is the output
run:

```
Fahrenheit |   Celsius

 150       |    51
 151       |    51
 152       |    52
 153       |    53
 154       |    53
 155       |    54
 156       |    54
 157       |    55
 158       |    55
 159       |    56
 160       |    56
 161       |    57
 162       |    58
 163       |    58
 164       |    59
 165       |    59
 166       |    60
 167       |    60
 168       |    61
 169       |    61
 170       |    62
 171       |    63
 172       |    63
 173       |    64
 174       |    64
 175       |    65
 176       |    65
 177       |    66
 178       |    66
 179       |    67
 180       |    68
 181       |    68
 182       |    69
 183       |    69
 184       |    70
 185       |    70
 186       |    71
 187       |    71
 188       |    72
 189       |    73
 190       |    73
 191       |    74
 192       |    74
 193       |    75
 194       |    75
 195       |    76
 196       |    76
 197       |    77
 198       |    78
 199       |    78
 200       |    79
 201       |    79
 202       |    80
 203       |    80
 204       |    81
 205       |    81
 206       |    82
 207       |    83
 208       |    83
 209       |    84
 210       |    84
 211       |    85
 212       |    85
 213       |    86
 214       |    86
 215       |    87
 216       |    88
 217       |    88
 218       |    89
 219       |    89
 220       |    90
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: the output didn't post in an orderly fashion but the conversions don't add up in my method Celsius to Fahrenheit (FtoC) the conversions are just fine

Comment: Heck: you want us to help, so please write up the question so that you think it contains all information; don't starting adding comments right afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

The equation is

```
F = C×9/5 + 32
```

For CtoF and

```
C = (F-32)×5/9
```

For FtoC

Si you are using a weird equation, that of course is giving you a wrong result

Answer (score 0):

you have a mistake in you formula, it should be (i - 32)*(5.0/9.0)